# Lists on eval inside a makefile

Tags: list, makefile, eval

I need some macros to be evaluated on targets but I can't get `OBJECT_FILE` to be evaluated by $^ aparently. this is my makefile:

```
#___________________________________build tools_________________________________

MKDIR    := mkdir
RM       := rm
CP       := cp
CD       := cd
COMPILER := gfortran

GENERAL_FLAGS       := -fno-automatic -static -I/usr/include -fimplicit-none
TESTING_DEBUG_FLAGS := -Og -g -fbounds-check -fbacktrace -pedantic -Wextra \
                   -Wall ${GENERAL_FLAGS}
RELEASE_FLAGS       := ${GENERAL_FLAGS} -Ofast

#______________________________macros de diretórios_____________________________

SRC_DIR     := src
BUILD_DIR   := build
RELEASE_DIR := release
DEBUG_DIR   := debug
TEST_DIR    := test
DIST_DIR    := dist

PROGRAM := ${DIST_DIR}/SimulArroz

#______________________________regras de compilação_____________________________

tests:   | TEST_PATHS ${PROGRAM}

TEST_PATHS:
    $(eval FLAGS        = ${TESTING_DEBUG_FLAGS})
    $(eval OBJECT_DIR   = ${BUILD_DIR}/${TEST_DIR})
    $(eval OBJECT_FILES = ${OBJECT_DIR}/Data.o ${OBJECT_DIR}/Model.o \
              ${OBJECT_DIR}/Control.o ${OBJECT_DIR}/Farmings.o \
              ${OBJECT_DIR}/Test_data.o ${OBJECT_DIR}/Test_main.o \
              ${OBJECT_DIR}/Test_subroutines.o)
    ${MKDIR} -p ${DIST_DIR}
    ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECT_DIR}

clean :
    ${RM} -fr ${BUILD_DIR}
    ${RM} -fr ${DIST_DIR}
    ${RM} -f seed.mod

run :
    ${CD} ${DIST_DIR} ; ./${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${OBJECT_FILES}
    ${COMPILER} ${FLAGS} -o $@ $^

${OBJECT_DIR}/%.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.f90
    ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECT_DIR}
    ${COMPILER} ${FLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

The result I get is:

```
gfortran -Og -g -fbounds-check -fbacktrace -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -fno-automatic -static -I/usr/include -fimplicit-none -o dist/SimulArroz 
gfortran: fatal error: no input files; unwilling to write output files
compilation terminated.
makefile:90: recipe for target 'dist/SimulArroz' failed
make: *** [dist/SimulArroz] Error 1
```

**update:**

I tried `secondary expansion` as pointed in comments but still, at last on my case it is giving the same result, here are the changes I've tried:

```
tests: FLAGS        := ${TESTING_DEBUG_FLAGS}
tests: OBJECT_DIR   := ${BUILD_DIR}/${TEST_DIR}
tests: OBJECT_FILES := ${TEST_OBJ_DIR}/Data.o ${TEST_OBJ_DIR}/Model.o \
              ${TEST_OBJ_DIR}/Control.o ${TEST_OBJ_DIR}/Farmings.o \
              ${TEST_OBJ_DIR}/Test_data.o ${TEST_OBJ_DIR}/Test_main.o \
              ${TEST_OBJ_DIR}/Test_subroutines.o

.SECONDEXPANSION:
tests: $$(PROGRAM)

${PROGRAM}: ${OBJECT_FILES}
    ${MKDIR} -p ${DIST_DIR}
    ${COMPILER} ${FLAGS} -o $@ $^

${OBJECT_DIR}/%.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.f90
    ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECT_DIR}
    ${COMPILER} ${FLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: The `${OBJECT_FILES}` would be expanded during parsing of the file, while the corresponding `$(eval)` would be evaluated when the "test" target is executed, which happens later. Do you really need to `$(eval)` something which doesn't have any dynamic content in it? Just define the variables the usual way and it should work.

Comment: This is just part of the makefile, testing is one of the make compilation rules I have, is the only one that use `Test_%.f90` files, debug and release use a different list of requisites for example. I would like a generic and concise way so I can use the two last targets for any compilation lists of objects. I should not evaluate each object as in: `${OBJECT_DIR}/%.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.f90`. Isn't this the adequate way, letting make evaluate what is needed from all files specified to be compiled? If there is a way to get this rule for different object lists I would appreciate guidance.

Comment: `a generic and concise way` - the GNU make is simply wrong tool for that. Though, yes, you can accomplish that - using the "secondary expansion" feature. I would advise to check BSD make which has straightforward means to do what you want, since it based on a conventional preprocessor, which is much better suited for such things compared to the GNU make.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still stuck in same problem, someway the `${OBJECT_FILES}` static pattern is not expanded in `${PROGRAM}`, giving nothing to `$^` again. I need to use GNU as a lot of people use MinGW to build it. I would like those qualities but if there is no solution I will go with a verbose one... I updated the question with my changes to try secondary expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I investigated it further, and as pointed in question comments, it is possible to solve my problem using `second expansion`, I have made it using `text function` too. As no one came with an answer I'm putting it here:

```
#___________________________________build tools_________________________________

MKDIR    := mkdir -p
RM       := rm
CP       := cp
CD       := cd
COMPILER := gfortran

# flags do compilador

GENERAL_FLAGS       := -fno-automatic -static -I/usr/include -fimplicit-none
TESTING_DEBUG_FLAGS := -Og -g -fbounds-check -fbacktrace -pedantic -Wextra \
                       -Wall ${GENERAL_FLAGS}
RELEASE_FLAGS       := ${GENERAL_FLAGS} -Ofast

#______________________________macros de diretórios_____________________________

SRC_DIR     := src
BUILD_DIR   := build
RELEASE_DIR := release
DEBUG_DIR   := debug
TEST_DIR    := test
DIST_DIR    := dist

test_FILES  := Data.o Model.o Control.o Farmings.o Test_Data.o Test_Main.o \
               Test_Subroutines.o 

#______________________________regras de compilação_____________________________

.PHONY: test clean run

test: FLAGS       := ${TESTING_DEBUG_FLAGS} -o
test: OBJ_DIR     := ${BUILD_DIR}/${TEST_DIR}
test: PROGRAM_DIR := ${DIST_DIR}/${TEST_DIR}
test: PROGRAM     := ${PROGRAM_DIR}/SimulArroz

.SECONDEXPANSION:
test: $${$$@_FILES}
      ${MKDIR} ${PROGRAM_DIR}
      ${COMPILER} ${FLAGS} ${PROGRAM} $($@_FILES:%o=${OBJ_DIR}/%o)

%.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.f90
    ${MKDIR} ${OBJ_DIR}
    ${COMPILER} -c ${FLAGS} ${OBJ_DIR}/$@ $<

clean :
    ${RM} -fr ${BUILD_DIR}
    ${RM} -fr ${DIST_DIR}
    ${RM} -f seed.mod

run :
    ${CD} ${DIST_DIR} ; ./${PROGRAM}
```

**but... I still cant figure why I can't just get a target like:**

```
${OBJ_DIR}/%.o: ${SRC_DIR}/%.f90
   ${MKDIR} ${OBJ_DIR}
   ${COMPILER} -c ${FLAGS} $@ $<
```

As `${OBJ_DIR}` did not expand if used in target. If someone can explain what is happening in this case, I would appreciate a lot.

I would like to thanks the suggestion I received in comments too.